# Необходима ли запятая перед вопросом

Tags: пунктуация

*Я не знаю, правильно или нет.*

Правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая поставлена правильно, она отделяет главное предложение *(Я не знаю)* от придаточного *(правильно или нет)*. Вы же видите две основы?

Просто в данном случае придаточное присоединяется не с помощью союза или союзного слова, а с посредством частицы "ли".

---

Способы присоединения придаточного изъяснительного предложения к главному с помощью:

...**[частицы ЛИ](http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)**:

*Запорожцы начали толкать под руку кузнеца, думая, **не с ума ли он сошел**.* (Н. В. Гоголь)

Comment: Вы уверены, что тут не бессоюзная связь? *Или* — сочинительный союз и относится к однородным сказуемым *правильно* и *нет*. *Ли* — не *или*!

Comment: Нет, не бессоюзная. Это разговорная конструкция с пропуском первой части двойного союза ЛИ - ИЛИ  Например:" Я спросил, идёт ли он со мной или мне идти одному"  — средство связи — двойной союз ли - или.